# Flask. Socket-io with gevent: [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable]

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to execute flask app with socket-io, using gevent, but receive error on start:

```
uwsgi[23312]: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x5645e3bee6a0 pid: 23312 (default app)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 23312)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 23315, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 23316, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 23317, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 23318, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 23319, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 23320, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 23321, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: *** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x5645e2778d30] ***
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 23322, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 23323, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 23324, cores: 1024)
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
uwsgi[23312]: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

my uwsgi_conf.ini is simple and only this lines matter:

```
http-websockets = true
http-socket = :1234
chmod-socket = 660
gevent = 1024
```

when i remove `gevent` line everything works correct without `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error

also i have 1:1 copy of this project on another server where everything run perfectly

UPDATE-1:
`gevent-early-monkey-patch = 1` if i remove this line i got different error:

```
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 26039)
DAMN ! worker 3 (pid: 26030) died :( trying respawn ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well when i install
`pip install gevent==1.4.0`

everything works perfectly, instead of new one gevent version

Comment: I have also noticed that the latest gevent works fine with Python 3.7, but shows the error with 3.8.